# MVC 4 Project with Membership Email Verification

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How do I add email verification to member registration in MVC 4? I found some examples but they were for MVC 3, and did not seem to work.

Are there any templates available that have this functionality already wired up?

Comment: are you using simplemembership?

Answer (score 1):

This is a high-level answer, but I think you should research Profile variables for ASP.NET Membership.  You can then store a boolean "requiresVerification" and "verificationCode" profile variable for each user set to true when the user is created.  During user creation also email a random code to their email address.

After that, build your page that requires the username, password, and the random code that was emailed.  If it all matches, set the profile variable to false (indicating that the address was verified).

Lastly, check that variable when the user attempts to sign on.  If it's true, don't let them (and re-point them to the verification page).